# How can I express in Scala class configuration option?

Tags: scala

In the title I provided use-case for the following behavior: the field should be publicly mutable and immutable for the class's own methods. Consider also that I essentially want single line per field, because the number of fields may be great. Also I want to have no-arg constructor.

Comment: You want to have `yourObject.someField = "someValue"` be acceptable (publicly mutable) but have `yourObject.someMethod` be **unable** to mutate `someField`?

Comment: Exactly! That is it!

Comment: If you use a `var`, you're going to have a mutable field.  The only way to make sure your internal methods don't mutate but still be mutable externally is... to not have them mutate it.

Answer (score 3):

The nearest I can think of that could satisfy what you want is to have a trait which only has accessor methods, and an implementation class that allows mutations. Pass the class type around wherever you need to be able to alter values, but reference it only as the trait wherever the values should be unalterable.

Comment: That is exactly the kind of solution I was considering and which I rejected by myself. It's so not DRY!